# How to do condtitional rendering in React and ES6 inside the map function

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to render an array of messages but would want it to render differently by class given a condition my code looks like this:

```
render() {
      return (
      <div>
      {this.props.messages.map((m, index) => (
          //if m.id === 1 render this:
          <p className={someClass1}>Hello, {m.message}!</p>
          //else render this:
          <p className={someClass2}>Hi, {m.message}!</p>
      ))}
      </div>);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can easily add logic to your map. you just need the contents to not be an inline return of a react component.

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.props.messages.map((m, index) => {
                if (m.id === 1){
                    return <p className={someClass1}>Hello, {m.message}!</p>
                }
                return <p className={someClass2}>Hi, {m.message}!</p>
            })}
        </div>
      );
  }
```

You can also do the same thing with a forEach outside of the return on your render like so

```
render() {
    const elems = [];
    this.props.messages.forEach( (m, index) => {
        if (m.id === 1) {
            elems.push(<p className={someClass1}>Hello, {m.message}!</p>);
        } else {
            elems.push(<p className={someClass2}>Hi, {m.message}!</p>);
        }
    return (
        <div>
            {elems}
        </div>
      );
  }
```